# Permission Denied Error and Service Unavailable, when starting jetty as a service

Tags: scala, plugins, playframework, jetty, sbt

I am trying to deploy my play app using jetty. I've successfully used the [play2-war plugin](https://github.com/play2war/play2-war-plugin), to make a war file out of my play application. I've also named it ROOT.war and placed said file in the webapps folder of my jetty installation. To install jetty I used [this post](http://techtraits.com/jetty9install/). I am totally new to jetty so I haven't touched jetty after the installation all I've done is

```
sudo service jetty start
```

to deploy my app. When I check x.x.x.x:8080, I see a 503 and also this

```
Problem accessing /. Reason:

Service Unavailable
```

This is my most recent log file in /opt/jetty/logs

```
20:42:05,521 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender[FILE] - openFile(/home/jetty/logs/application.log,true) call failed. java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/jetty/logs/application.log (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/jetty/logs/application.log (Permission denied)
    at      at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at      at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
    at      at ch.qos.logback.core.recovery.ResilientFileOutputStream.<init>(ResilientFileOutputStream.java:28)
    at      at ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender.openFile(FileAppender.java:149)
    at      at ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender.start(FileAppender.java:108)
    at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction.end(AppenderAction.java:96)
    at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.callEndAction(Interpreter.java:317)
    at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.endElement(Interpreter.java:196)
    at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.endElement(Interpreter.java:182)
    at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.EventPlayer.play(EventPlayer.java:62)
    at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:149)
    at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:135)
    at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:99)
    at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:49)
    at      at play.api.Logger$$anonfun$configure$3.apply(Logger.scala:256)
    at      at play.api.Logger$$anonfun$configure$3.apply(Logger.scala:256)
    at      at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:245)
    at      at play.api.Logger$.configure(Logger.scala:256)
    at      at play.api.Application$class.$init$(Application.scala:272)
    at      at play.core.server.servlet.DefaultWarApplication.<init>(Play2Server.scala:122)
    at      at play.core.server.servlet.WarApplication.<init>(Play2Server.scala:105)
    at      at play.core.server.servlet.Play2WarServer$.apply(Play2Server.scala:43)
    at      at play.core.server.servlet.GenericPlay2Servlet.contextInitialized(GenericPlay2Servlet.scala:45)
    at      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:798)
    at      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:444)
    at      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:789)
    at      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:294)
    at      at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1341)
    at      at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1334)
    at      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741)
    at      at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:497)
    at      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741)
    at      at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:497)
    at      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at      at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:41)
    at      at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:186)
    at      at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:498)
    at      at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:146)
    at      at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:180)
    at      at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
    at      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:609)
    at      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:528)
    at      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:391)
    at      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:313)
    at      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at      at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:150)
    at      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at      at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:560)
    at      at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:235)
    at      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:387)
    at      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:354)
    at      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at      at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1255)
    at      at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at      at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1174)
    at      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at      at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:310)
    at      at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:786)
    at      at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:111)
```

And this

```
20:42:05,542 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender[FILE] - openFile(/home/jetty/logs/application.log,true) call failed. java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/jetty/logs/application.log (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/jetty/logs/application.log (Permission denied)
    at      at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at      at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
    at      at ch.qos.logback.core.recovery.ResilientFileOutputStream.<init>(ResilientFileOutputStream.java:28)
    at      at ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender.openFile(FileAppender.java:149)
    at      at ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender.start(FileAppender.java:108)
    at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction.end(AppenderAction.java:96)
    at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.callEndAction(Interpreter.java:317)
    at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.endElement(Interpreter.java:196)
    at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.endElement(Interpreter.java:182)
```

and finally this

```
[^[[31merror^[[0m] c.j.b.h.AbstractConnectionHook - Failed to obtain initial connection Sleeping for 0ms and trying again. Attempts left: 0. Exception: null.Message:path to './dbChard/chard.db': '/opt/jetty/./dbChard' does not exist
2014-09-25 20:42:05.784:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:main: Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@4362f992{/,file:/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-ROOT.war-_-any-9217408542040048607.dir/webapp/,STARTING}{/ROOT.war}
Configuration error: Configuration error[Cannot connect to database [default]]
    at      play.api.Configuration$.play$api$Configuration$$configError(Configuration.scala:94)
    at play.api.Configuration.reportError(Configuration.scala:743)
    at play.api.db.BoneCPPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(DB.scala:247)
    at play.api.db.BoneCPPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(DB.scala:238)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:272)
    at play.api.db.BoneCPPlugin.onStart(DB.scala:238)
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:91)
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:91)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply$mcV$sp(Play.scala:91)
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:91)
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:91)
    at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
    at play.api.Play$.start(Play.scala:90)
    at play.core.server.servlet.WarApplication.<init>(Play2Server.scala:112)
    at play.core.server.servlet.Play2WarServer$.apply(Play2Server.scala:43)
    at play.core.server.servlet.GenericPlay2Servlet.contextInitialized(GenericPlay2Servlet.scala:45)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:798)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:789)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1341)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1334)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:609)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:528)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:391)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:560)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1174)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:786)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:111)

Caused by:
java.sql.SQLException: path to './dbChard/chard.db': '/opt/jetty/./dbChard' does not exist
at org.sqlite.Conn.open(Conn.java:103)
    at org.sqlite.Conn.<init>(Conn.java:57)
    at org.sqlite.JDBC.createConnection(JDBC.java:77)
    at org.sqlite.JDBC.connect(JDBC.java:64)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.obtainRawInternalConnection(BoneCP.java:363)
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.<init>(BoneCP.java:416)
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource.getConnection(BoneCPDataSource.java:120)
    at play.api.db.BoneCPPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(DB.scala:240)
    at play.api.db.BoneCPPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(DB.scala:238)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:272)
    at play.api.db.BoneCPPlugin.onStart(DB.scala:238)
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:91)
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:91)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply$mcV$sp(Play.scala:91)
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:91)
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:91)
    at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
    at play.api.Play$.start(Play.scala:90)
    at play.core.server.servlet.WarApplication.<init>(Play2Server.scala:112)
    at play.core.server.servlet.Play2WarServer$.apply(Play2Server.scala:43)
    at play.core.server.servlet.GenericPlay2Servlet.contextInitialized(GenericPlay2Servlet.scala:45)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:798)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:789)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1341)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1334)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:609)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:528)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:391)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:560)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1174)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:786)
```

This is my first time using jetty, so I am not very familiar with many of the conventions,the commands, and debug methods, which is why I am asking my question here, hoping for an answer. Any and all help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you,everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, some problems with the instructions at http://techtraits.com/jetty9install/

- NPN cannot be configured with a simple copy/paste.  If you have a newer version of Java, then you must also upgrade your version of Jetty to get the `npn` that is specific for your version of Java. (And if you use Java 8, then you need to use `alpn`, not `npn`)
- There nothing in those instructions for the `${jetty.home}` vs `${jetty.base}` concepts.  (while not required, it does making configuring Jetty, and upgrading Jetty far easier)
- Don't use Jetty 9.1.1, use the latest version, `9.2.3.v20140905`
- These instructions are systemd specific, but not to worry, as it seems your specific environment seems to support it (esp since you got far enough to trigger these errors)
- If you have JSP in use, then **do not use** openjdk, it has known bugs that cannot be worked around.  Use the official Oracle JDKs. (Since you are using the play framework, this is probably not really relevant to you)

As for the errors / warnings, you have ...

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/jetty/logs/application.log (Permission denied)
```

This is permissions on your filesystem issue.

You'll either need to verify that the `jetty` user has the rights to create that file, or the directories above it.

```
path to './dbChard/chard.db': '/opt/jetty/./dbChard' does not exist
```

This error is pretty straight forward, your database configuration is making a relative path reference to a file that doesn't exist from where you started your jetty instance.  Just change that configuration to be an absolute path.

Comment: This response was quite helpful! However I am not sure how to address the db issue. I have a feeling it might have to do with the play2war plugin, and how it creates the war file. I do not have direct access to the code used by the plugin. Therefore, I wanted to ask if there is a way to point jetty to the apps db using the absolute path. Any ideas guys? @Joakim thanks for your response!

Comment: I've solved the problem it was a matter of using the absolute path to the db instead of a relative path.